# How to enable `projection` in pymongo query class `find()`?

Tags: pymongo, pymongo-3.x

[`find()`](https://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html?highlight=find#pymongo.collection.Collection.find) official link

```
for doc in db.tasks.find(filter={'state':'successful'},projection=['analysis.bandgap'])‌​: 
    print doc
```

I tried to set projection as a list or dict, but neither will work for limit the output of find(). How to set projection properly?

Comment: How did you do it? show us your code.

Comment: @user3100115 Thank you. A shorten code is as followed: `for doc in db.tasks.find(filter={'state':'successful'},projection=['analysis.bandgap'])‌​: print doc`

Comment: please add sample documents with the expected result using the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/36943425/edit) link